# PHP files are note interpreted after ubuntu release upgrade.. why?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I've upgraded an Ubuntu server from 18 to 22.04.

PHP version is 8.1.2
Apache/2.4.52

After that, my .php files are not interpreted but apache2 show source code... Why ?

Thanks

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `php -v` will not work, right?

Comment: Php -v work: 
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2023 14:01:49) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you (re)enabled PHP for Apache2? Therefore check the `mods-enabled` folder in Apache's installation directory for a `php` file.

If you cannot fine any file, try running `sudo a2enmod php8.1`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Was the PHP Version also updated from <7.4 in that Ubuntu Server update?
This could be the result of PHP's short tags having gotten deprecated with 7.4+ if you are still trying to use them in PHP 8
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags